# Replacing a text in list within textfile

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently doing an assignment where I have to make an Apartment Registering program. I saved the apartment info like this in a textfile:

```
['B01','3','Master: TP_1','TP_2','TP_3']
['B02','2','Master: TP_1','TP_2','TP_3']
['B03','1','Master: TP_1','TP_2','TP_3']
['B04','0','Master: TP_1','TP_2','TP_3']
['B05','1','Master: TP_1','TP_2','TP_3']
['B06','2','Master: TP_1','TP_2','TP_3']
['B07','3','Master: TP_1','TP_2','TP_3']
['B08','2','Master: TP_1','TP_2','TP_3']
['B09','1','Master: TP_1','TP_2','TP_3']
['B10','0','Master: TP_1','TP_2','TP_3']
```

Now, whenever a new student register to the apartment, I would like to add 1 to the number of occupants, which is the second value in the list. I would also like to replace the TP with student ID number.

```
def apartmentRegister(): #REGISTERING APARTMENT
    AorB=input("Would you like to register into Apartment A or B? (A/B)")
    if AorB==("A") or AorB==("a"):
        room=input("Insert room number: ")
        f=open("Apartment_A.txt", "r")
        for line in f.readlines():
            if not line or line =="\n":
                continue
            A_register=literal_eval(line)
            if A_register[-5]==(room):
                if A_register[-3]==("TP_1"):
                    f=open("Apartment_A.txt", "a")
                    TPagain=input("Please input your TP number: ")
                    new=line.replace("TP_1",TPagain)
                    f.write(new+"\n")
                    print("You're all set")
                f.close()
    elif AorB==("B") or AorB==("b"):
        room=input("Insert room number: ")
        g=open("Apartment_B.txt", "r")
        for line in g.readlines():
            if not line or line =="\n":
                continue
            B_register=literal_eval(line)
            if B_register[-5]==(room):
                if B_register[-3]==("Master: TP_1"):
                    g=open("Apartment_B.txt", "a")
                    TPagain=input("Please input your TP number: ")
                    new=line.replace("TP_1",TPagain)
                    g.write(new+"\n")
                    print("You're all set")
                g.close()
```

The whole code works... just the fact that I couldn't replace the values/text that I want to replace... Instead it adds a new line in the text file instead.

Comment: You open the files using `open(filename, "a")` where the `a` stands for `append at the end` (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). You rather want to open it, read all lines, change the lines accordingly, and then save all lines overriding the whole file.

Comment: I did opened it with "a". I opened it first with "r" then with "a"

Comment: And that's the problem. ;)

Comment: You should check what `r`, `a` or `w` do when you open files.

Comment: The bug in code aside, the clean way of doing this would be using CSV files or a small database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something along these lines:

```
# This is the content of the file after processing
new_contents_A = []

# Read in all lines and save them to the list
with open("Apartment_A.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if not line or line =="\n":
            new_contents_A.append(line)
            continue
        A_register=literal_eval(line)
        if A_register[-5]==room and A_register[-3]==("TP_1"):
            TPagain=input("Please input your TP number: ")
            new=line.replace("TP_1",TPagain)
            new_contents_A.append(new)
        else:
            new_contents_A.append(line)

# Override the file with the now changed data
with open("Apartment_A.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in new_contents_A:
        f.write(line)
```